# ffplay cannot play more than one song

Tags: c++, winapi, ffmpeg, sdl

i have taken ffplay.c file  from http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/ffplay_8c-source.html and re edited it to a cpp file to embed in my win32 gui application . i have made the following changes to it.

1. made the int main function into a local function as follows, i can pass the HWND to embedd the player

```
void Ffplay::play_song(string file, HWND parent, bool* successfull)
{
    int flags;
    VideoState* is;
    input_filename = file; 
    /* register all codecs, demux and protocols */
#if CONFIG_AVDEVICE
    avdevice_register_all();
#endif
    //avformat_network_init();
    //check whether the filename is valid
    if (input_filename.empty())
    {
        logger.log(logger.LEVEL_ERROR, "filename %s is not valid\n", file);
        return;
    }
    if (display_disable)
    {
        video_disable = 1;
    }
    flags = SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_TIMER;
    if (audio_disable)
        flags &= ~SDL_INIT_AUDIO;
    else
    {
        /* Try to work around an occasional ALSA buffer underflow issue when the
         * period size is NPOT due to ALSA resampling by forcing the buffer size. */
        if (!SDL_getenv("SDL_AUDIO_ALSA_SET_BUFFER_SIZE"))
            SDL_setenv("SDL_AUDIO_ALSA_SET_BUFFER_SIZE", "1", 1);
    }
    if (display_disable)
        flags &= ~SDL_INIT_VIDEO;
    SDL_SetMainReady();
    if (SDL_Init(flags))
    {
        logger.log(logger.LEVEL_ERROR, "Could not initialize SDL - %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        logger.log(logger.LEVEL_ERROR, "(Did you set the DISPLAY variable?)\n");
        return;
    }
    //Initialize optional fields of a packet with default values.
    //Note, this does not touch the data and size members, which have to be initialized separately.
    av_init_packet(&flush_pkt);
    flush_pkt.data = (uint8_t*)&flush_pkt;

    if (!display_disable)
    {
        int flags = SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN;
        if (alwaysontop)
#if SDL_VERSION_ATLEAST(2,0,5)
            flags |= SDL_WINDOW_ALWAYS_ON_TOP;
#else
            logger.log(logger.LEVEL_INFO, "SDL version doesn't support SDL_WINDOW_ALWAYS_ON_TOP. Feature will be inactive.\n");
#endif
        if (borderless)
            flags |= SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS;
        else
            flags |= SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE;
        SDL_InitSubSystem(flags);
        ShowWindow(parent, true);
        //window = SDL_CreateWindow(program_name, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, default_width, default_height, flags);
        window = SDL_CreateWindowFrom(parent);
        SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "linear");
        if (window) {
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
            if (!renderer)
            {
                logger.log(logger.LEVEL_ERROR, "Failed to initialize a hardware accelerated renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
            }
            if (renderer)
            {
                if (!SDL_GetRendererInfo(renderer, &renderer_info))
                {
                    logger.log(logger.LEVEL_INFO, "Initialized %s renderer.\n", renderer_info.name);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!window || !renderer || !renderer_info.num_texture_formats)
        {
            logger.log(logger.LEVEL_ERROR, "Failed to create window or renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            return;
        }
    }

    is = stream_open(input_filename.c_str(), file_iformat);
    if (!is)
    {
        logger.log(logger.LEVEL_ERROR, "Failed to initialize VideoState!\n");
        return;
    }
    //the song is playing now
    *successfull = true;
    event_loop(is);
    //the song has quit;
    *successfull = false;
}
```

2. changed the callback functions as the static ones couldn't be used by c++ eg,

```
void Ffplay::static_sdl_audio_callback(void* opaque, Uint8* stream, int len)
{
    static_cast<Ffplay*>(opaque)->sdl_audio_callback(opaque, stream, len);
}
```

closing doesn't change from the main file to close the audio and sdl framework

```
void Ffplay::do_exit(VideoState* is)
{
    abort = true;
    if(is)
    {
        stream_close(is);
    }
    if (renderer)
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    if (window)
         SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
#if CONFIG_AVFILTER
    av_freep(&vfilters_list);
#endif
    avformat_network_deinit();
    SDL_Quit();

}
```

i call the functions as follows from main gui

```
ft=std::async(launch::async, &Menu::play_song, this, songs_to_play.at(0));
```

the `menu::play_song` function is:

```
void Menu::play_song(wstring song_path)
{
    ready_to_play_song = false;
    OutputDebugString(L"\nbefore song\n");
    using std::future;
    using std::async;
    using std::launch;

    string input{ song_path.begin(),song_path.end() };
    Ffplay ffplay;
    ffplay.play_song(input, h_sdl_window, &song_opened);

    OutputDebugString(L"\nafter song\n");
    ready_to_play_song = true;
}
```

THE PROBLEM is i can only play one song . if i call the `menu::play_song` function again the sound is missing and the video/art cover is occasionally missing also. it seems some resources are not been released or something like that.

i have localised the proble to this function

```
int Ffplay::packet_queue_get(PacketQueue* q, AVPacket* pkt, int block, int* serial)
{

    MyAVPacketList* pkt1;
    int ret;
    int count=0;
    SDL_LockMutex(q->mutex);

    for (;;) 
    {


        if (q->abort_request)
        {
            ret = -1;
            break;
        }

        pkt1 = q->first_pkt;
        if (pkt1) {
            q->first_pkt = pkt1->next;
            if (!q->first_pkt)
                q->last_pkt = NULL;
            q->nb_packets--;
            q->size -= pkt1->pkt.size + sizeof(*pkt1);
            q->duration -= pkt1->pkt.duration;
            *pkt = pkt1->pkt;
            if (serial)
                *serial = pkt1->serial;
            av_free(pkt1);
            ret = 1;
            break;
        }
        else if (!block) {
            ret = 0;
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            logger.log(logger.LEVEL_INFO, "packet_queue before");
            SDL_CondWait(q->cond, q->mutex);
            logger.log(logger.LEVEL_INFO, "packet_queue after");

        }
    }
    SDL_UnlockMutex(q->mutex);
    return ret;
}
```

the call to `SDL_CondWait(q->cond, q->mutex);` never returns

Answer (score 1):

First, sorry the question was a bit vague since i couldn't upload much of the code as it was long that's why i posted the link to original one which is similar to mine, the only difference is I've changed functions from C static ones to C++ public ones.

The problem was the variable `SDL_AudioDeviceID audio_dev`

Assigning the variable using 
`audio_dev = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &wanted_spec, &spec, SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_FREQUENCY_CHANGE | SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_CHANNELS_CHANGE)` was not assigning the variable as planned and when it came to closing the audio device using `SDL_CloseAudioDevice(audio_dev);` the audio device variable was 0 therefore the device wasn't been closed and as a result the second song was missing sound or video could hang.
This is a result of using various threads that calls the local callback functions that are been cast to a static nature as expected from the SDL api.

The answer was changing the device varible to static one, `static SDL_AudioDeviceID audio_dev;` therefore the variable could be accessed from any place in the program